# Change table colors every block of 10 IDs

Tags: php

I need to make a table that needs to change in 3 different colors loop, every block of 10 rows

Like this

```
Id 1 -> 10 Red

Id 11 -> 20 Green

Id 21 -> 30 Blue

Id 31 -> 40 Red
```

And so on

This is the code i been trying with 2 different colors

```
<?php
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 40; $i++) {
    if($i % 10 == 0)
      {echo "<td class=\"dark\">$i</td>";}
    else 
      {echo "<td class=\"light\">$i</td>";}
   }
?>
```

But the class changes to "dark" every 10, like 10, 20, 30, 40 and the other values remain in "light"

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like the following:

```
$useColor = '';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 40; $i++) {
    if($i % 10 == 0)
      if ($useColor == 'color1') {
        $useColor = 'color2';
      } elseif ($useColor == 'color2') {
        $useColor = 'color3';
      } elseif ($useColor == 'color3') {
        $useColor = 'color4';
      } else {
        $useColor = 'color1';
      }
    }
    echo "<td class=\"$useColor\">$i</td>";}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First shift your id like this:

```
Id 0 -> 9 Red

Id 10 -> 19 Green

Id 20 -> 29 Blue

Id 30 -> 39 Red
```

and so on.

There is a sequence for each color id set

For the red we have

```
Id 0 -> 9
Id 30 -> 39
Id 60 -> 69
Id 90 -> 99
Id 120 -> 129
```

and so on.

Now again notice another sequence

```
0
30
60
120
```

All of this number when divided by 30 give a remainder of 0

Similarly For the Green Id

```
Id 10 -> 19
Id 40 -> 49
Id 70 -> 79
Id 100 -> 109
Id 130 -> 139
```

Again notice another sequence `10, 40, 70, 100, 130`. All of this number gives a remainder of 10 when divided by 30

Lastly  For Blue Id, We have:

```
Id 20 -> 29
Id 50 -> 59
Id 80 -> 89
Id 110 -> 119
Id 140 -> 149
```

`20, 50, 80, 110, 140` when divided by 30 gives a remainder of 20.

Now is time for the code

```
$j = 0; //$j return the last digit of the integer
$k = 0; //difference btw $i and $j 
for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000; $i++) {
    $j = (string)$i;// type casting int to string
    $j = (int) $j[strlen($j)-1]; //get last digit from $i
    $k = $i - $j; //get rid of the last digit in $i

    if ($k % 30 == 0) echo '<br>red';
    if ($k % 30 == 10) echo '<br>green';
    if ($k % 30 == 20) echo '<br>blue';
}
```

This works for me cause i tested the code. I hope it satisfies you.

You can also use the condition:

```
if ($k % 30 == 0) {echo '<br>red';}
elseif ($k % 20 == 0) {echo '<br>green';}
elseif ($k % 10 == 0) {echo '<br>blue';}
```

This works great as well. what matters the most in this problem is finding and subtracting `$j` from `$i`.